# Accessing local files with d3.json no longer working for firefox?

Tags: firefox, d3.js, topojson

Up until last week, accessing a local file in firefox was not a problem, as per below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Albers Projection</title>
<style>

path {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Map obtained here:
//https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json
d3.json("US.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  d3.select("svg").append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states))
      .attr("d", d3.geo.path());
});

</script>
```

However, as of this week, there is an error at the d3.json step:

uncaught exception: [object XMLHttpRequest]

I do not believe this is due to the older versions of D3 either, as it persists with V4 and topojson.v2, except the error here is:

uncaught exception: [object ProgressEvent]

I have not been able to find anything about this. What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/68.0/releasenotes/#fixed)

> Local files can no longer access other files in the same directory.

More details are given under the [security advisories](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730)

> #CVE-2019-11730: Same-origin policy treats all files in a directory as having the same-origin

The associated bug is currently non-accessible, but there's related discussion in [bug 803143](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=803143). I don't think they have yet documented which options, if any, are available to developers to keep working with local multi-file documents.

You might have to fall back to the old jsonp technique or use a static webserver.

For local development you can override this behavior with about:config ->  `privacy.file_unique_origin = false`, but beware that this exposes you to the kind of local data exfiltration that this change is intended to fix.